# Swap rows which take effect only on the under diagonal elements

Tags: matlab, matrix

Having square matrix `A` and I want to swap between 2 row on it ,  but with constraint that this swap would take effect only on the elements which are under the diagonal in both row  .

Example  -

```
1 2 3 4
3 6 7 8 
6 5 4 2
9 4 6 7
```

swap betwen row1 and row2 would return same matrix because there is no elements which are under the diagonal in row 1 .

but swap between row2 and row3 would give -

```
1 2 3 4
6 6 7 8 
3 5 4 2
9 4 6 7
```

which actually swapped just between 2 element index (3,1) and (2,1) because there is no more elements in row2 which are under to diagonal .

How to obtain this function with no explicit loop by given the two required row indexes   ?

Regular swap could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939738/swapping-rows-and-columns/4940630#4940630)  .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
A([row1 row2],1:row1-1) = A([row2 row1],1:row1-1)
```

Note that `row1 <= row2` for this to work. If necessary, you can simply use `min` and / or `max` to find which is smallest / largest.

Comment: +1, note that `row1` and `row2` must be sorted (i.e., `row1<row2`)

Comment: As I examine it holds for `row1<=row2` too .

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
function A = swapRowsBelowDiagonal(A, a,b)

    m = min(a,b)-1;
    [A(a,1:m), A(b,1:m)] = swap(A(a,1:m), A(b,1:m));
end

function [y,x] = swap(x,y), end % NOTE: no body, just for fun :)
```

Comment: you could have also done it with DEAL: `[A(b,1:m),A(a,1:m)] = deal(A(a,1:m), A(b,1:m));`